# converting string to dictionary using json.loads

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I'm trying to pass some json data extracted from a JavaScript file.

I have the following variable in my python code. I get the string from file.read(). I know the below will be set as a dict if pasted into a python code as is.

```
resultStr = {"inst":{"summary":{"statistics":[],"wa_recursive":"100.000%","files":11,"dus":11}},"du":{"summary":{"statistics":[{"type":"stmt","data":"Statement Coverage","status":"covered","weight":1,"rhits":"100.000%","rtotal":"100.000%"},{"data":"Statements","rhits":86.000,"rtotal":86.000},{"data":"Subprograms","rhits":0.000,"rtotal":0.000},{"type":"branch","data":"Branch Coverage","status":"covered","weight":1,"rhits":"100.000%","rtotal":"100.000%"},{"data":"Branch paths","rhits":42.000,"rtotal":42.000},{"data":"Branches","rhits":21.000,"rtotal":21.000},{"type":"toggle","data":"Toggle Coverage","status":"uncovered","weight":1,"rhits":"94.410%","rtotal":"100.000%"},{"data":"Toggle bins","rhits":304.000,"rtotal":322.000},{"data":"Signal bits","rhits":150.000,"rtotal":161.000}],"wa_recursive":"98.137%","files":11,"dus":11}}};
```

When i pass this string into the json loader

```
json.loads(resultStr)
```

I get the following exception

```
  File "C:\Python34\lib\json\__init__.py", line 318, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\json\decoder.py", line 346, in decode
    raise ValueError(errmsg("Extra data", s, end, len(s)))
ValueError: Extra data: line 1 column 825 - line 1 column 826 (char 824 - 825)
```

To simplify its failing on the last part of the string

```
"wa_recursive":"98.137%","files":11,"dus":11}}};
```

I've tried to just enter it manually and it is recognized as a dictionary in the python code.

I cant seem to find any fault with it so some assistance would be appreciated :)

Thank you :)

Comment: The thing your passing to `json.loads` is a dictionary, not a string. I don't get any error when I load it by the way. Did you put the semicolon in the string?

Comment: the value is a string IE resultStr is reported as a string. I might have shown it wrong but the value i have i get from a file.read(). ITs correct i also get a dict if I just paste the above into my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following works fine for me. Did you keep the semicolon in the string?

```
import json
resultStr = '{"inst":{"summary":{"statistics":[],"wa_recursive":"100.000%","files":11,"dus":11}},"du":{"summary":{"statistics":[{"type":"stmt","data":"Statement Coverage","status":"covered","weight":1,"rhits":"100.000%","rtotal":"100.000%"},{"data":"Statements","rhits":86.000,"rtotal":86.000},{"data":"Subprograms","rhits":0.000,"rtotal":0.000},{"type":"branch","data":"Branch Coverage","status":"covered","weight":1,"rhits":"100.000%","rtotal":"100.000%"},{"data":"Branch paths","rhits":42.000,"rtotal":42.000},{"data":"Branches","rhits":21.000,"rtotal":21.000},{"type":"toggle","data":"Toggle Coverage","status":"uncovered","weight":1,"rhits":"94.410%","rtotal":"100.000%"},{"data":"Toggle bins","rhits":304.000,"rtotal":322.000},{"data":"Signal bits","rhits":150.000,"rtotal":161.000}],"wa_recursive":"98.137%","files":11,"dus":11}}}'
decodedData = json.loads(resultStr);
print(decodedData);
```

Comment: Though it was not really there it reported the error